# Can I partial match a string in visual workflow?

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

My use case is as follows

in my flow a user enters a subject into a text input field. I then place the input into a variable. I then perform a record lookup on a custom object to find any records that match that variable. I then have a dynamic choice that displays the records.

When finding records the criteria I am using is
Custom_field - Contains - Variable

this works fine when the custom field is an exact match for the text string in the variable. Example - If I enter Account team in the input field, it will find a record with a string like "I have an account team" in it. If I search "Team account" it returns null. It only matches an exact string.

What I need is to match based on any word in the string. A like function or something similar.

Is there any way to loop through a string and search each word or a way to perform a partial match?

To Confirm, The Contains function only matches an exact string. So if the variable contains "123" and the custom field on the record contains "321" it does not match.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick "contains" as the operator. From the user input no need to add wild cards.

[image]